# Passing current time in Javascript to GraphQL AWSDateTime column

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify

I have a GraphQL table `Channel` with the column `dateOn` of the type `AWSDateTime`

In my React app I am calling a mutation to create a new `Channel`. Here's the relevant code:

```
const createChannel = `
mutation createChannel {
  createChannel(input:{
    title:"${title}"
    dateOn:${Date.now()}
    slug: "${slug}"
    authorId: "${authorId}"
  }) {
    id title slug authorId
  }
}
`;
```

AWS accepts a datetime string in this format:

`The AWSDateTime scalar type represents a valid extended ISO 8601 DateTime string. In other words, this scalar type accepts datetime strings of the form YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ`

How would I go about passing the current time in this format in Javascript?

Answer (score 19):

You can do this with straight javascript `new Date().toISOString()`. However this should really be handled by the resolver on the backend instead of passing the value from the frontend.

Also moment.js is a large dependency, unless you plan to use it extensively I would go with something like `date-fns`.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking to avoid a library for such a trivial thing. Will go with your approach.

Comment: Also should say I would prefer to do this on the backend (in AWS AppSync). Just not sure how currently. If someone has an approach I'll mark that the answer.

Comment: @pejmanjohn AppSync already creates a 'createdAt' and 'UpdatedAt' fields, you can use them instead: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/401

Comment: Thanks for this. Doing table seeding this is very helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can agree on handeling localisation in the backend. Shouldn't it be done closer to the user as different users from different contries call the api and it'll be lot extra work to manage it in the backend?

Comment: not really a localisation issue, the frontend should still handle converting to the user's timezone

Answer (score 2):

Ended up being simple with `moment.js`

First I installed it in my project

`npm install moment --save`

Then I included it in the relevant .js file

`import moment from "moment";`

And here's what my final mutation looked like

```
const createChannel = `
mutation createChannel {
  createChannel(input:{
    title:"${title}"
    dateOn: "${moment().format()}"
    slug: "${slug}"
    authorId: "${authorId}"
  }) {
    id title slug authorId
  }
}
`;
```